# Rewrite conditions for URLs like this

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I go about writing the conditions for mod_rewrite to make this example happen?

Have a URL this like...

```
http://domain.com/recent/5
```

Render this page...

```
http://domain.com/index.php?view=recent&page=5
```

And if there is no page number specified (note I want it to work with or without trailing-slash)...

```
http://domain.com/recent/
```

It will default to page 1...

```
http://domain.com/index.php?view=recent&page=1
```

But when someone just goes to the root domain...

```
http://domain.com
```

I want this page to render...

```
http://domain.com/index.php?view=popular&page=1
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+) /index.php?view=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?view=popular&page=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. After hours of searching/reading, I learned a lot from that!